# I m trying to display value in textbox .But m getting the error Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

```js
var result = document.getElementById("textbox1");

result.value = salary;
```

```html
<input id="textbox1" name="texbox1" type="text" >
```

Comment: You haven't defined salary. Maybe you are trying to do the opposite? `var salary = result.value;`

Comment: Because you're trying to access a variable before it is present in the DOM. Either wrap the code in `DOMContentLoaded` callback, or move the `<script>` to the end of body

Comment: the function `var result = document.getElementById("textbox1");` was called before the element `<input id="textbox1" name="texbox1" type="text" >` existed. Call the js after the element was loaded.

Comment: Welcome to SO! See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I have the whole code .But it is too long how can i send it through comment

Comment: @AamirNawab As I said in the previous comment, move the `<script>` from head to the end of `<body>` or wrap the code in `DOMContentLoaded` event callback and let me know if that work for you.